# ORACLE PL SQL : Select all and process every records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to have your advise how to implement the plsql. Below is the situation that i want to do..

1. `select * from table A`
2. `loop - get each records from #1 step, and execute the store procedure, processMe(a.field1,a.field2,a.field3 || "test",a.field4);`

i dont have any idea how to implement something like this. Below is sample parameter for processMe

```
processMe(
    number_name IN VARCHAR, 
    location IN VARCHAR,
    name_test IN VARCHAR,
    gender IN VARCHAR )
Begin 
   select objId into obj_Id from tableUser where name = number_name ;
   select locId into loc_Id from tableLoc where loc = location;
   insert into tableOther(obj_id,loc_id,name_test,gender) 
      values (obj_Id ,loc_Id, name_test, gender)
End;
```

Comment: Row by row processing in a loop, generally, is not a good idea. What exactly that `processMe` stored procedure does?

Comment: i just add some process. but this is just a sample. By the way, why you said that this is not a good idea using loop? i interested to know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR rec IN (SELECT * 
              FROM table a)
LOOP
  processMe( rec.field1,
             rec.field2,
             rec.field3 || 'test',
             rec.field4 );
END LOOP;
```

does what you ask.  You probably want to explicitly list the columns you actually want in the `SELECT` list rather than doing a `SELECT *` (particularly if there is an index on the four columns you actually want that could be used rather than doing a table scan or if there are columns you don't need that contain a large amount of data).  Depending on the data volume, it would probably be more efficient if a version of `processMe` were defined that could accept collections rather than processing data on a row-by-row bases as well.

Answer (score 1):

> i just add some process. but this is just a sample. By the way, why
>   you said that this is not a good idea using loop? i interested to know

Performance wise, If you can avoid *looping* through a result set executing some other DMLs inside a loop, do it.

There is PL/SQL engine and there is SQL engine. Every time PL/SQL engine stumbles upon a SQL statement, whether it's a `select`, `insert`, or any other DML statement, it has to send it to the SQL engine for the execution. It calls context switching. Placing DML statement inside a loop will cause the switch(for each DML statement if there are more than one of them) as many times as many times the body of a loop has to be executed. It can be a cause of a serious performance degradation.  if you have to loop, say, through a collection, use `foreach` loop, it minimizes context switching by executing DML statements in batches.

Luckily, your code can be rewritten as a single SQL statement, avoiding `for` loop entirely:

```
insert into tableOther(obj_id,loc_id,name_test,gender) 
    select tu.objId
         , tl.locid
         , concat(a.field3, 'test')
         , a.field4                       
      from table a
      join tableUser tu
        on (a.field1 = tu.name)
      join tableLoc tl
        on (tu.field2 = tl.loc)
```

You can put that `insert` statement into a procedure, if you want. PL/SQL will have to sent this SQL statement to the SQL engine anyway, but it will only be one call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable declared using a cursor rowtype. Something like this:

```
declare

cursor my_cursor is
  select * from table;

reg my_cursor%rowtype;

begin 
  for reg in my_cursor loop
    --
    processMe(reg.field1, reg.field2, reg.field3 || "test", reg.field4);
    --
  end loop;
end;
```